# Thread.sleep() vs Thread.onSpinWait

Tags: java

I have a spin-wait loop that is busy-waiting for a flag to be set. However, it can take **a lot** of time for that to happen - minutes, or even hours.

Would [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) be more efficient than [Thread.onSpinWait​()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#onSpinWait--)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you wanted to see a short example about [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) and its long-available `wait()` and `notify/All()` methods? (They are already [there](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/17.doc.html) in [JLS 1.0](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/), from 20+ years ago)

Say no more:

```
public class NotifyTest {
  private boolean flag = false;
  public synchronized boolean getFlag() {
    return flag;
  }
  public synchronized void setFlag(boolean newFlag) {
    flag = newFlag;
    notifyAll();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final NotifyTest test = new NotifyTest();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.printf("I am thread at %,d, flag is %b\n",
                          System.currentTimeMillis(), test.getFlag());
        synchronized (test) {
          try {
            test.wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        System.out.printf("I am thread at %,d, flag is %b\n",
                          System.currentTimeMillis(), test.getFlag());
      }
    }).start();

    System.out.printf("I am main at %,d, flag is %b\n",
                      System.currentTimeMillis(), test.getFlag());
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    test.setFlag(true);
    System.out.printf("I am main at %,d, flag is %b\n",
                      System.currentTimeMillis(), test.getFlag());
  }
}
```

If your wait loop has anything else to do, `Object.wait()` has variants with timeout too.

So objects can be `wait()`-ed on and then waiting threads can be notified (one of the waiters via `notify()` or all of them via `notifyAll()`), and they do not even have to know about each other.
As both waiting and notifying has to happen inside a synchronized block, it is safe and possible to start the block, check the variable/flag/anything, and issue the wait conditionally (just these constructs are not shown here).

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea these methods existed - thank you!

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#onSpinWait--) of `Thread#onSpinWait`:

> The runtime may take action to improve the performance of invoking spin-wait loop constructions.

`Thread#sleep` does not do this, but rather releases the processor to another runnable thread until its sleep time has elapsed.

If I were you, I would redesign your system to use interrupts (events) rather than polling (busy waiting), as that would result in a better performance boost than either `Thread#sleep` or `Thread#onSpinWait`.

Answer (score 2):

Neither sleep nor a spin lock is what you want in this situation.   sleep is the wrong choice because you don't know how long you're going to need to sleep beforehand.  Doing some sort of spin lock loop is wrong because spin locks are busy waits and thus consume CPU cycles and are only really meant for very short waits in anticipation of a resource becoming available very quickly.  What you want to do here is set up a semaphore.  Have thread 1 wait for the semaphore to be set by thread 2.